# More examples about box macros in context

Tags: context

I'm using ConTeXt MKIV and I want to use `\tbox`, `\rbox`, etc. in my macros. But I do not find many examples. I just need the basics of howto use them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: `\documentclass` in context?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My bad. Standard text... I never used context. @ viper please provide an MWE with everything which might be needed in order to compile your document.

Answer (score 4):

The `\lbox`, `\cbox` and `\rbox` are a normal `\vbox` with the exception that they set a default alignment for their content.

```
\starttext

\vbox{\input ward }

\blank

\lbox{\input ward }

\blank

\cbox{\input ward }

\blank

\rbox{\input ward }

\stoptext
```

[image]

The `\tbox` and `\bbox` put their content in a `\hbox` and change afterwards the height and depth values of the box. For the `\tbox` the new value for the box height is the height of a strut and for a `\bbox` the new value of the depth is the depth of a strut.

```
\setupexternalfigure[location=default]

\useexternalfigure[cow][cow][frame=on,height=3\lineheight]

\starttext

\ruledhbox\bgroup
          \externalfigure[cow]
    \tbox{\externalfigure[cow]}
    \bbox{\externalfigure[cow]}%
\egroup

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to add that I see these macros as being useful for low-level commands where speed is an issue. For user-level commands it is better to use `\framed` and change the alignment with the `align` key and change the vertical location with the `location` key.